# Automatically change special constants on deplyoment?

Tags: php, netbeans

I was wondering if it's possible to instruct Netbeans to modify php code before uploading sources to remote web site.

In my case I use XAMPP to test locally on my pc the project I'm working on.
However my remote webserver hosting the "release" version of my sources could have some peculiarities requiring altering the code on upload, like static sources placed on multiple hosts.

At present date, I'd need to manually patch the code on every upload, OR make a local copy of the source files, and do the modification prior uploading.

So here comes my question. Any possibility to instruct NB to do the modifications automatically, when deploying sources?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but you could define the constants depending on the IP, if its 127.0.0.1 define them one way, if its not define them as the remote site values, if you want an example I can add one

Comment: I'm not sure if the IP address of the deployment web server is static but I don't think so... it's a shared hosting server. How could I achieve this in the CSS stylesheet?

Comment: I believe you want to to manage two copies of the same file depending on the running server.
I'd like to avoid this technique, that involves two copies of the same file... would rather have one CSS file and change constants on the fly before deploying

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change the variables values, you can change the values in a conditional code.
Simple example:

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'productiondomain.com'){
    define('URL_BASE','productiondomain.com/');
    define('UPLOAD_FOLDER','/var/www/productiondomain.com/uploads/');
} else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost'){
    define('URL_BASE','localhost/my_dev_folder/');
    define('UPLOAD_FOLDER','/home/my_user/projects/my_dev_folder/uploads/');
}
?>
```

And in your code use (very simple example):

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"${URL_BASE}contact\" >Contact</a>";
//... in another file
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, UPLOAD_FOLDER ."name_that_you_want");
?>
```